# What is the time complexity assigning a datastructure-copy to a new instance?

Tags: c++11, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity, avl-tree

I have just a small question:
I have an AVL tree and want to copy it 1:1 to a new instance. What I do is I create a new instance of the AVLTreeClass and assign it the tree I want to copy with an equal sign (in C++11).

Do I have to worry about time complexity? Or does this run in O(1)?

Thank you very much for your help!

FunkyPeanut

Comment: `Do I have to worry about time complexity? Or does this run in O(1)?` Who knows if implementation is left to imagination.

Comment: Hmm.. I was hoping for a generic answer... Would this be answerable if I simplified the question?: What is the time complexity of copying a data structure like e.g. a standard array with 20 entries to a new instance of array?

Comment: Nobody knows, but I don't think there is any way to make it run in anything but O(n) - you need to copy each node exactly once.

Haven't seen standard, but I highly doubt that it would allow for 'building up' the tree instead of making a copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is completely implementation-dependent and without seeing the code I don't think anyone can give a definitive answer. However, there are various reasonable implementations that would be O(1), O(n), and O(n log n).

A naive implementation of a copy constructor might work by iterating across all the nodes in the old tree and calling the public insert method to add each one to the new tree. This requires O(log n) time per element of the old tree, so the complexity would be O(n log n). However, this is not particularly efficient. An alternative approach would be to blindly make a deep copy of the tree. This would require O(1) work per tree node and since there are n nodes in the tree, the runtime would be O(n). Without any other indications, I'd suspect that your runtime is **O(n)**, and most programmers (I believe) would also assume this unless you gave an indication otherwise.

If you suspect that copies will be common but updates rare, you could alternatively consider using [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) and have the copy share the internal representation of the tree, making a full, deep copy only if either the original or the copied tree changes. This would result in time O(1) for copies, but would then cost O(n) or O(n log n) if you then made a change.

Alternatively, you might have a [persistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) AVL tree. In that case, any mutating operation on the tree runs in time O(log n) and produces a new tree representing the effect of the operation without actually breaking the old version of the tree. In that case, copies can be made in O(1) by sharing the representation with no later penalties to the insert and delete operations.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's all and more than I wanted to know! Thank you very much :)